# loss of quality when saving many images IOS

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

I'm having problem with saving many images. I'm using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext. For example my input image is 200kb and output image is just 35 kb. How can i save my images without loss of quality. Here is code example:

```
BOOL first = YES;
mSavedImage = mImageView.image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mImageView.frame.size, YES, 0.0);
DLog(@" FRAME %@",NSStringFromCGSize(mImageView.frame.size));
DLog(@"%i",mEditingView.subviews.count);
for (NSInteger i = mEditingView.subviews.count-1; i>=0; i--){
    if ([[mEditingView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[FSShopItem class]]) {
        DLog(@"is shopitem");

        FSShopItem *lPrewSubview = [mEditingView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        FSShopItem *lSubview = nil;
        if (first) {
            [mImageView.image drawInRect:mImageView.frame];
            first = NO;
        }
        else{
            lSubview = [mEditingView.subviews objectAtIndex:i+1];                   
            [lSubview.image drawInRect:lSubview.frame];
        }
        DLog(@" FRAME %@",NSStringFromCGRect(lPrewSubview.frame));
        [lPrewSubview.image drawInRect:lPrewSubview.frame];
    }
}
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIImage *lImageForLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_logo.png"];
    CGRect lRect = CGRectMake(mEditingView.frame.size.width - lImageForLogo.size.width, mEditingView.frame.size.height - lImageForLogo.size.height, lImageForLogo.size.width, lImageForLogo.size.height);
    [lImageForLogo drawInRect:lRect];
}
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    UIImage *lImageForLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_logo.png"];
    CGRect lRect = CGRectMake(mEditingView.frame.size.width - lImageForLogo.size.width, mEditingView.frame.size.height - lImageForLogo.size.height, lImageForLogo.size.width, lImageForLogo.size.height);
    [lImageForLogo drawInRect:lRect];

}
mSavedImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return mSavedImage;
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the image with some zoom / pan? Is that your goal?

Comment: no i'm trying to save all imageviews what i have to one picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the `mImageView.frame.size` rectangle is much smaller than the `logo.png` images, so they are draw in a smaller rectangle than their original size. What you need to do is create a context that is much larger - say 4 or 8 times larger. Now the core image will have much more detail (but of course be larger too). You can then render this image in a smaller rectangle, and lose resolution, or show it at its native size for full resolution.

The key point here is that your are working with pixels - not vector art - and so if you ever draw an image in a smaller rectangle than its native size, you will lose detail.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly using the image view frames, decide on how big the result image should be and then mutate the frames with `CGRectInset` based on the scaling factor between the screen size (the frame coordinate space) and the full size.